# Notepad++ copy from and past to specific places on a string

Tags: notepad++, copy-paste, forms

I have a huge HTML form.

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" value="whatever1" id=""><label for="">whatever1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="whatever2" id="" ><label for="">whatever2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="whatever3" id=""><label for="">whatever3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="whatever4" id=""><label for="">whatever4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="whatever5" id=""><label for="">whatever5</label>
    ...
</form>
```

I was wondering if it is possible to use Notepad++ to copy the text from value="[copy this]" and paste it into id="[paste here]" and for="[paste here]" on every line.

If anyone has the solution to this, every web developer out there will be very happy :D

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to move the value for ANY lines that contain "value", "id" and "for" attributes, you can use this generic regex find-and-replace:

Find what=`^(.+value=")([^"]+)(".*id=")[^"]*(".*for=")[^"]*(".*)$`

Replace with=`\1\3\2\4\2\5`

This is useful if you don't care about the name of the element or the content of other attributes like "type".

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect and saved me a whole lot of trouble :) I needed to Replace with=`\1\2\3\2\4\2\5` but I figured it out :) Notepad++ rocks :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex with Notepad++ with the Replace functionnality.
Be sure to check the "regex" checkbox.

In the "Find what" input : `<input type="checkbox" value="(.*)" id="(.*)"><label for="(.*)">(.*)</label>`

In the "Replace with" input : `<input type="checkbox" value="\1" id="\1"><label for="\1">\4</label>`

Now, you can "Replace All"